# Multiple checkboxes with same id and one needs to be selected - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

There are multiple checkboxes with same id, in asp.net repeater control. User can select either email or phone against each record in repeater rows.

In following example; there are two rows, if you select the email icon in first row then it ticks relavent checkbox which is fine but if you tick the email icon on the next row then it will untick the first row checkbox instead of ticking the one next to it.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id*=divchkemail]").click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("image-email");

    if ($('#chkemail').prop('checked')) {
      $("#chkemail").prop('checked', false);
    } else {

      if ($('#chkphone').prop('checked')) {
        $("#chkphone").prop('checked', false);
        $("#divchkphone").toggleClass("image-phone");
      }
      $("#chkemail").prop('checked', true);
    }

  });

  $("[id*=divchkphone]").click(function() {


    $(this).toggleClass("image-phone");

    if ($('#chkphone').prop('checked')) {
      $("#chkphone").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
      if ($('#chkemail').prop('checked')) {
        $("#chkemail").prop('checked', false);
        $("#divchkemail").toggleClass("image-email");
      }

      $("#chkphone").prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    .image-phone-disabled {
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/74FcgdS.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
    }
    .image-phone {
      background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/LwsHkOt.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
    }
    .image-email-disabled {
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/khd2NG8.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
    }
    .image-email {
      background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/y5KE9jx.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divchkemail" class="image-email-disabled" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="chkemail" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl01$chkemail"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divchkphone" class="image-phone-disabled" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="chkphone" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl01$chkphone"></input>

    </td>

  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>


<span>

  
    

</span>

<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divchkemail" class="image-email-disabled" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="chkemail" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl02$chkemail"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="divchkphone" class="image-phone-disabled" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="chkphone" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl02$chkphone"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span>
    
 

</span>
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xuz/48/

Comment: What is the desired behavior? To only allow one or the other to be checked? Or just associate each icon with the check next to it?

Comment: Only one can be selected per row. So in first row you can either select email or phone not both, and same for the next row.

Comment: Is it even allowed to have multiple element with same id? Checkboxes should have the name, shouldn't them?

Comment: That is why you need RADIO boxes with same name and not checkboxes

Comment: no i can't use radio box because user can uncheck all options.

Comment: multiple elements with the same ID is not valid HTML. JS can not handle that. You need to make the ID unique ( e.g `chkemail_0` `chkemail_1` and so on.. )

Comment: This is what I have found: `<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"....`, at least this is how I retrieve the checkbox info in php

Comment: ideally you should be using separate id's for inputs. i've tried to make ur example work but i would still insist that you use unique id's for inputs. try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xuz/49/

Comment: @Sushil; thanks for the jsfiddle. It doesn't completly work, how can i find the checkbox next to first one. Only one checkbox can be checked at a time.

Comment: oh. i thought u wanted them both to be checked. let me update the fiddle

Comment: Only one can be selected per row. So in first row you can either select email or phone not both, and same for the next row. Also, user can un select both.

Comment: its a big mess but u can try this http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xuz/50/ let me know if it works for u

Comment: @user1263981 did it work for u?

Comment: @user1263981 i've added that as an answer. can you please mark it as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75817/discussion-between-user1263981-and-sushil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you are selecting element by id and which is duplicate. You have to find your required element traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree so that selector only select elements within current row by setting a area of elements. Here is working code.

```js
$(function () {
    $("[id*=divchkemail]").click(function (e) {
        var currentRow = $(e.target).parents().closest('table');
        $(this).toggleClass("image-email");

        if ($(currentRow).find('#chkemail').prop('checked')) {
            $(currentRow).find('#chkemail').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            var chkPhoneInCurrentRow = $(currentRow).find('#chkphone')
            var divchkInCurrentRow = $(currentRow).find('#divchkphone')
            if ($(chkPhoneInCurrentRow).prop('checked')) {
                $(chkPhoneInCurrentRow).prop('checked', false);
                $(divchkInCurrentRow).toggleClass("image-phone");
            }
            $(currentRow).find('#chkemail').prop('checked', true);
        }   
    });

    $("[id*=divchkphone]").click(function (e) {
        var currentRow = $(e.target).parents().closest('table');
        $(this).toggleClass("image-phone");

        if ($(currentRow).find('#chkphone').prop('checked')) {
            $(currentRow).find('#chkphone').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            var chkEmailInCurrentRow = $(currentRow).find('#chkemail')
            var divchkInCurrentRow = $(currentRow).find('#divchkemail')
            if ($(chkEmailInCurrentRow).prop('checked')) {
                $(chkEmailInCurrentRow).prop('checked', false);
                $(divchkInCurrentRow).toggleClass("image-email");
            }
            $(currentRow).find('#chkphone').prop('checked', true);
        }   
    });
});
```

```css
    .image-phone-disabled {
 background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/74FcgdS.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat ;
 width:34px;
 height:34px;  
    }
   .image-phone {
     background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/LwsHkOt.png);  
        background-repeat:no-repeat ; 
     width:34px;
     height:34px;
    }

   .image-email-disabled {
 background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/khd2NG8.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat ;
 width:34px;
 height:34px;  
    }
   .image-email {
     background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/y5KE9jx.png);  
        background-repeat:no-repeat ; 
     width:34px;
     height:34px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divchkemail" class="image-email-disabled" /> </td>
         <td>     <input id="chkemail" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl01$chkemail"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divchkphone" class="image-phone-disabled" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="chkphone" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl01$chkphone"></input>
            
        </td>
        
    </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>


    <span>

  
    

</span>

<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="divchkemail" class="image-email-disabled" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="chkemail" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl02$chkemail"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="divchkphone" class="image-phone-disabled" /></td>
         <td>
               <input id="chkphone" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabRequests$Requests$cndt1$FindInspector$rptSearch$ctl02$chkphone"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span>
    
 

</span>
```

Here is working fiddle.
    http://jsfiddle.net/hannnan/noukkjsq/

Comment: great solution as it works no matter where the checkboxes are in the table. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/noukkjsq/1/

Comment: Hmm, disappointed. I find my version is much more elegant, not to mention much more generic with no need to know the class names and only one function for any sets of contacts. No need for my function to know the ID which should be unique in any case.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

I gave the rows a class of contact. It can also work without the class on the rows by using `$("table > tr")` instead. No need to know the exact class names and can handle any number of sets allowing the correct unique IDs for the fields.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ovsfczsw/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".contact").on("click", function (e) {
        var $div = $(this).find("div"); // the div on the clicked row
        var divClass = $div.prop("class"); // its class
        var $checkbox = $(this).find("input"); // the checkbox
        var check = $checkbox.is(":checked"); // whether or not it is checked
        if (e.target.type != "checkbox") { // we clicked somewhere else
            check = !check; // toggle
            $checkbox.prop("checked", check); // set the check
        }
        if (check) { // are we enabling?
          if (divClass.indexOf("disabled") != -1) { // disabled?
              $div.removeClass(divClass).addClass(divClass.replace("-disabled", ""));
          } 
        }
        else { // disable it
          $div.removeClass(divClass).addClass(divClass + "-disabled");
        }


        var $otherContact=$(this).siblings("tr"); // the sibling row
        if (check) {
            $div = $otherContact.find("div");
            divClass=$div.prop("class");
            if (divClass.indexOf("disabled") == -1) {
              $div.removeClass(divClass).addClass(divClass+"-disabled");
            }    
            $checkbox=$otherContact.find("input"); // the checkbox
            if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) $checkbox.prop("checked",false);  
        }    

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

although you must use unique id's for elements, given your scenario I've written down this fiddle.

i've used this `$(this).parent().next('td').find('input:checkbox');` to find the checkboxes

please try this http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xuz/50/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the same IDs for everything - the JS cannot differentiate between the two rows. So you click the second row's icon, the first element it finds with your ID (`#divchkemail`) it performs the action on, which is in the first row.